# PHP convert psd to jpg, selecting image layers

Tags: php, image, layer, imagick, psd

I want to be able to select which layers from a .PSD image are merged into the final .JPG output image.

I can merge all of the layers in the image with:

```
$im = new Imagick('test.psd');
$im->flattenImages();
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
$im->writeImage('test.jpg');
```

However the .psd contains about 10 layers and I want to be able to specify which specific layers should be merged together, to produce the final image.

For example I want to merge only layer numbers 3, 5 and 10 or the layers with names "RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"

Comment: And then what? Discard the other layers? I don't think you can have multiple layers in JPEG.

Comment: @mark: hence the "flattenImages" call...

Comment: I guess I'm mis-understanding what he's asking then. If you are merging three layers together and then flattening, it's going to merge all the layers with the three already merged in the flatten call, so why merge just the three?

Comment: btw flattenImages returns the flattened image it doesn't do it in place e.g. "$merged = @$imagick->flattenimages();"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although hsz's answer is correct, and is the best way when the images are very large, it does require you to know ahead of time which layers you want to merge.

You can do the same thing more programmatically by using `setIteratorIndex` to access the individual layers and adding them to an output image.

```
    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath("../images/LayerTest.psd"));

    $output = new \Imagick();
    $imagick->setIteratorIndex(1);
    $output->addImage($imagick->getimage());

    $imagick->setIteratorIndex(2);
    $output->addImage($imagick->getimage());

    $merged = @$output->flattenimages();
    $merged->setImageFormat('jpg');
    $merged->writeImage('test.jpg');
```

Comment: How do you access to the layer name?

Comment: @santyas fyi, asking a different question in a comment five years after the answer was made is not usually going to result in a response. i) I have no idea ii) you should ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

You can access third layer with

```
test.psd[3]
```

Just try with:

```
$im = new Imagick(array('test.psd[3]', 'test.psd[5]', 'test.psd[10]'));
```

Comment: The correct syntax appears to be more like `realpath("test.psd")."[2]"` to pass the correct path to Imagick. However I don't seem able to get the image flattening to work at all.

Comment: Uh, the flattening works if you get the layers in the right order :-P

Comment: That's why I was confused, I can't understand the context here because the question lacked clarity.

Comment: How do you access to the layer name? @hsz